# On the legality of arming yachts and other recreational craft at sea

Tags: is-x-legal, law-of-the-sea, defense

Is it legal or applicable to arm yachts or other recreational vessels for defense against piracy, thieves, terrorism, etc?

[image: pretty cannon]

Comment: You may want to read Ansel J. Halliburton's [Pirates versus mercenaries: purely private transnational violence at the margins of international law](https://dx.doi.org/10.2139/ssrn.1755214) (2010)

Comment: *"If a PMC were to attack pirates offensively, that would itself be an act of piracy. The law does allow self-defense, though, so placing armed guards on a ship and fighting back when attacked is fine"* — [Ansel Halliburton](https://www.quora.com/Why-are-Somali-pirates-not-being-hanged/answer/Ansel-Halliburton)

Comment: I suspect that a lot of navies would probably be inclined to regard a yacht with a deck-mounted gun as a pirate vessel until proven otherwise.

Comment: Why not accept the answer?

Answer (score 13):

### Gun control laws

The moment you enter the 12 nautical miles zone of a country, you need to abide by its weapon laws. Most functioning large-caliber and fully-automatic weapons are not allowed in civilian hands globally. The moment the ship leaves the 12 nautical miles zone, the country law of its flag applies, so unless you happen to start in the US with a duly registered curio/relic deck gun with proper stamps... you'll have a hard time being allowed to have the thing on board in the first place, and entering any other country's water is pretty much violating their gun control laws and gun import laws.

### Ship hulls don't support them.

That deck gun there is a type of [Bofors 40mm L/60 twin mounting - 40x311mmR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bofors_40_mm_L/60_gun). That means, its installation weighs upwards of half a ton, as that's the smallest carriage setup according to Wikipedia. [Navweapons](http://www.navweaps.com/Weapons/WNUS_4cm-56_mk12.php) helpfully provides gun weights of roundabout half a ton per gun. That puts the minimum weight at about that of a [PAK 40](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7.5_cm_Pak_40), but as Navweapons tells us, a US Mark 1 Twin clocks in at 4.4 to 5.8 tons including guns. All on the one mounting spot.

With the bulk they are, no fiberglass ship hull could support that much load on the gun's small footprint. It needs a steel-hulled superyacht to even bear the deck load of such an installation. If your ship is the size of a coastguard or navy vessel, it probably *is* such a ship redesigned, a commercial fishing boat (similar specs), a cargo vessel, a large cruise vessel, or built to your specifications from the ground up.

Comment: There's no "somewhat akin" about it; it is an anti-aircraft mounted Bofors.

Comment: @TheDaleks Found the data... Navwqeapons for the resuce! I'm rather sure that's a USN Mk1 mounting or British Mk 5 mounting...

Comment: Yachts get a seat upgrade and chrome flash suppressors; and you have to reduce the number of hot tubs by one.

Comment: @PhilSweet a Hot-Tub only weighs at best 2 tons filled with water.^^

Comment: I'd have guessed, Ship superstructure couldn't handle the weight. But, Rhinemetals smaller automated deck guns that don't penetrate hull/deck seem like a high road

Comment: @LazyReader you underestimate the weight of mountings: in North Carolina's final revision before finalizing the construction, 6 machine gun mounts and positions of .50 cal were eliminated to save 13 tons.